# A question about matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have never learned matrices in my school. I'm currently about to be a junior in  high school. Through videos I know how to add and multiplying matrices. However I often see people relating them with vectors and doing some pretty interesting things. As far as I am concerned there just like a list of numbers, with a purpose I cannot see. What can you tell me about matrices.

Comment: Try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160328/what-is-the-usefulness-of-matrices) for a start.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) is another reading I would recommend