# Prove the following are equivalent: $\det(A)\ne 0$ and Nullity$(A) = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Not really sure how to go about this, I know that nullity is the dimension of the kernel but what would the kernel of a matrix be? Unless we are considering determinant as a map then the kernel would be $\det(A) = 0$ which gives the required result? Furthermore, if $\det(XI-A)$ is not 0 so $\text{null}(XI-A)$ is not 0 why does this imply that $(XI-A)v = 0$ (found this line in my notes)

Comment: Hint: $N(T)= \left \lbrace v \in V: T(v)=0 \right \rbrace.$ You also have by Dimension theorem that $\text{rank(}T) + \dim N(T)= \dim V.$

Comment: Are you allowed to use any other pieces of the Invertible Matrix Theorem?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about the definitions.  The statement you're trying to prove is:

> For a square matrix $A$, $\det(A) \neq 0$ if and only if the nullity of $A$ is $\{0\}$

In this context, the *nullity* refers to the kernel of the linear transformation given by the matrix $A$.  Note that $A$ is often used interchangeably with its induced linear tranformation,
$$
T_A:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n, \qquad T_A(x) = Ax
$$
So: you are meant to show that $\det(A) \neq 0$ if and only if $\{x: Ax = 0\} = \{0\}$.  That is, $\det(A) \neq 0$ if and only if $Ax = 0$ has the unique solution $x = 0$.

---

In some contexts, the nullity is used to refer to the *dimension* of the kernel of $T_A$ as above.  However, this is not the meaning intended for this statement.  If we were to use that definition, we might say that $\det(A) \neq 0$ if and only if the nullity of $A$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $nullity(A)$ is a non negative integer, not a set as you have written in the question.

Let A be the matrix representation of the linear transformation we have. [$Det(A)\neq0\implies$ A is a full rank matrix,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628925/relation-between-determinant-and-matrix-rank) all the rows or columns of $A$ is linearly independent$\implies$the system $Ax=0$ will have the trivial solution only, $i.e.Ker(A)=\{0\}\quad$and hence  $null(A)=0,$ and null space

Comment: ah that makes sense, can you explain why nullity(XI-A) not equal to 0 implies (XI-A)v=0?

Comment: Nullity(xI-A) not equal to zero means there is at least one non zero vector (say v) in the Null space of (xI-A), i.e. at least one non zero vector (in this case v) is mapped to 0 under the transformation (xI-A) i.e. (xI-A)v=0. And is these cases, x is called the eigenvalue and corresponding v is known as eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

First, i think you misunderstood the concept of the kernel. 
The kernel is the set of all x such that T(x) = 0, i.e. all x such that Ax=0. (Where T is a map that takes x to Ax)

Since det(A) is not zero, then the equation Ax=0 has the trivial solution x=0. Hence kernelT = {0} (or nullity(A)={0}).

You can also see it from different perspective, since det(A) is not zero, then the columns are linearly independent. Now you have T(x)=x1A1 + x2A2 + x3A3 + ..... +xnAn  where xs are numbers and Ai are the columns of A. We see that A1,..., An are linearily independent, so imageT or RankA=n.(or you can directly say it since they are linearly i dependent).
DimT= RankA + DimNullityA
So DimNullityA=0. So only the vector 0 belongs to Nullity of A, hence Nullity(A)={0}.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please take a look at [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about formatting your answer to make it more readable.