# Relation between rank and determinant of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any direct or indirect relation between rank and determinant of a matrix ie if one  matrix $A$ has determinant a and rank $N$ and other matrix $B$ has determinant $a^2$ then can I find the rank of matrix $B$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Do you mean square matrices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relation between determinant and matrix rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628925/relation-between-determinant-and-matrix-rank)

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.  This seems like a perfectly legit question.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this question is first of all only well-defined if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices. So we assume that $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

- If we have $\det(A)=a\neq 0$ we can immediately conclude that $A$ has full rank, $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$. As $a\neq 0$ we also have $\det(B)=a^2\neq 0$ and we get $\operatorname{rank}(B)=n$.
- If we have $\det(A)=0$ we can conclude that $\operatorname{rank}(A)<n$, the same goes for $B$ in this case. But we can neither conclude that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$ nor $\operatorname{rank}(A)<\operatorname{rank}(B)$ nor $\operatorname{rank}(A)>\operatorname{rank}(B)$; in short we don't know jack about the ranks. For this see the examples below.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

All matrices have determinant $0$, but we have $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2,\operatorname{rank}(B)=1,\operatorname{rank}(C)=0$.