# Another way to find kernel and image using submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, matrix-rank

I'm teaching linear algebra and one of my students came to me with a different way to find the kernel and the image of a linear transformation, that doesn't use Gauss-Jordan reduction:

[image: look subsection 2, find the subspaces...]

SOLUTION:

1. The matrix $A$ is

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-14 & -6 & 2 \\
-10 & -4 & 2 \\
6 & 2 & -2
\end{array}\right)
$$

2. The kernel of $L$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ containing the vectors $\boldsymbol{v}=x, y, z$ such that it yields $L(\boldsymbol{v})=\mathbf{0}$, that is

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-14 & -6 & 2 \\
-10 & -4 & 2 \\
6 & 2 & -2
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$

which is an algebraic linear system having rank 2 , because

$$
\operatorname{det}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-14 & -6 & 2 \\
-10 & -4 & 2 \\
6 & 2 & -2
\end{array}\right)=0
$$

and the minor of order 2

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-4 & 2 \\
2 & -2
\end{array}\right)
$$

highlighted in the matrix $A$

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-14 & -6 & 2 \\
-10 & -4 & 2 \\
6 & 2 & -2
\end{array}\right)
$$

has determinant not equal to zero. From this minor we get the system

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-4 y+2 z=10 t \\
2 y-2 z=-6 t
\end{array}\right.
$$

in which we have given the arbitrary value $x=t$ to the unknown $x$, that lays outside the minor highlighted in the matrix $A$. The solution is then

$$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-2 \\
1
\end{array}\right) t
$$

that is the kernel is spanned by the basis vector $(1,-2,1)$. The image of $L$ is spanned by all those vectors whose components are contained inside the minor highlighted in the matrix $A$, that is we have the basis of the image

$$
\mathcal{B}_{I m(L)}=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}
-3 \\
-2 \\
1
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
-1
\end{array}\right)\right\},
$$

where the second and third column of $A$ have been divided by 2 .

$\hspace{2cm}$

I know how to solve it using G-J reduction, and I understand what he does to explain why $rank(A)=2$ but after that, I don't have any idea what he's using and I didn't find in the bibliography or Google some kind of possible explanation. (about how he get the basis of kernel and image)

Can someone explain the reasoning to me?

Comment: The rank ($A$) = the size of the largest nonzero minor of $A$. See **Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra** by Carl Meyer, page 466.

Comment: This link may [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628925/relation-between-determinant-and-matrix-rank). Also, next you can use the observation that rank = no. of independent rows, so y=we interpret that only two of the equations in the system are linearly independent, so there must be one free variable.

Comment: The title should be changed if the question is about determining the rank based on minors.

Comment: I know what you said about rank, what I don't know is how he find a basis for the kernel and the image using the submatrix highlighted